# Displying message after delteing jqgrid row.Response.Response Text display full HTML page

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I am using Jqgrid. I want to display Delete msg according to server Response .
 but as i am using response.responsText i am getting full HTML page Content.. help me

```
afterComplete: function(response,postdata,formid) {
    alert("'"+response.responseText+"'")
}
```

```cs
DataTable dr = new DataTable();
da.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand("select * from CustomerOrders where QuotationID='" + ID + "'", conn);
conn.Open();
da.SelectCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
da.Fill(dr);
conn.Close();

if (dr.Rows.Count > 0)
{
    Response.Write("dddd");
}                     
else
{
    da.DeleteCommand = new SqlCommand("delete from QuotationTemplates where QuotationID='" + ID + "'", conn);
    conn.Open();
    da.DeleteCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
    conn.Close();
    da.DeleteCommand = new SqlCommand("delete from Quotations where ID ='" + ID + "'", conn);
    conn.Open();
    da.DeleteCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
    conn.Close();
    Response.Write("nave");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be helpful to know which one ASP.NET technology you use. For example you can use ASHX to return any type of data which you need.

In general [Response.Write](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1463ysyw%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) *append* information to the response. You can use [Response.ClearContent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.clearcontent%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) (or `Response.Clear`) or [Response.ClearHeaders](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.web.httpresponse.clearheaders%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) to clear the current response. Moreover you can consider to set [Response.ContentType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.web.httpresponse.contenttype%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) to change the default `"text/html"` value to any other value like `"text/plain"` for example.

You can use [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/), [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) or "Network" tab of Developer Tools of Internet Explorer (press <kbd>F12</kbd> to start) or Google Chrome to trace the HTTP traffic between jqGrid and the your Server.

You can use additionally [ajaxDelOptions](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aform_editing#properties2) Ajax options like `ajaxDelOptions: {dataType: "text"}`, but I think it's not really required to solve your problem. I suppose that the origin of the problem is on the server side only (in your ASP.NET application).

Comment: thanks for the reply... Response.responseText[0] worked for me. It is giving me first letter of REsponse.Write("ddd") by using this word i solve my problem..

Comment: @Naveen: It's no problem! Now you increased your reputation and can "place" your opinion on any page of stackoverflow: you have right to vote up any question or answer (up to [30 votes per day](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5213)) which you find on the stackoverflow and which you find helpful. So **you can help other people to find *really helpful* information on the stackoverflow**, because the voting count if the main criteria used by searching engine. Best wishes!